# How do elections prediction works

Tags: predictive-models, polling, elections

Here in my country it's time to choose a president. So some institutions make surveys about how many votes (in %) the candidates are gone get in the poll day. The population is about 200 million peoples, but to make these surveys about 2000 people are asked their opinions. How it's possible to predict the result of the election with only such small number of the population?

Comment: I was expecting a less technical answer to be honest...

Comment: You can predict the results using far fewer than 2000 people: even one well-chosen person will do.  The issue, therefore, is *how accurately and precisely* can the result be predicted? Accuracy requires selecting the sample with great care, using procedures that ensure the sample results are likely to reflect the voting.  Precision increases with *sample* size and scarcely depends on the population size.  In a well-designed survey of 2000 people, the precision is usually small enough (a few percent) to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

so for one thing the variability only decreases with the square root of the number of people by the law of large numbers - so there is a diminishing returns effect on adding more people to the sample

furthermore people use stratified sampling - collecting samples from each age group (etc) and weighting by their known electoral proportions